# setting tableviewcell height to show full inner/nested uitableview with dynamic height cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am populating inner tableview in parent tableview cells cellForRowAt delegate and then assigning inner tables content size height to its height constraint constant. but not working as expected. it seems once inner table is loaded, there is no way to reload outer cell to adjust height.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` after filling in the internal tableView.